# 'In' of a python for loop access series values, where as 'in' of an if statement access series index, Why the inconsistency?

Tags: python, pandas, series

Assuming 'm' is a series with index as 1,2,....12 and values as jan, feb,....dec,

```
var = 1
if var in m: 
      print(var*20)
```

In above, the condition checks if 'var' is present in the index of m (1,2.....12) and prints 20

But, when 'in' is used in a for statement, it iterates through the series' values instead of series' index

```
for var in m: 
      print(var)
```

Above,  prints all the month names  (jan, feb..... dec)

Why is that the 'in' of the first piece of code (if block) searches in series index and the 'in' of the for statement iterates through the values of the series. Why is the behavior inconsistent ? Is there an explanation/logic behind this ?

Comment: @eyllanesc the question that was already answers (to which my question is a duplicate) doesn't seem to have clear answers or am I missing something ? Because answer say the in keyword looks for index  (here index of the series), but not sure why the in of a for loop accesses the series values instead of index. Can you please explain/elaborate

Comment: I have not closed your question, just edit your post

Comment: There is no guarantee of consistency between these two operations. You are operating from a false premise.

Comment: @tjt see the linked duplicate I added. [Here is a link to the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-operations) concerning the `x in y` membership testing expression. [Here is the documentation for iterable types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typeiter) and the [glossary entry for iterable](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#iterable) to for details about iterables/iterators in Python

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga The linked duplicates helps and they answer my question. Thank you very much